# Why is Traefik unable to generate ACME certificates for my domains?

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, traefik

Issue obtaining ACME certificates in Traefik for TLS (SSL) setup

I'm encountering difficulties while trying to obtain ACME certificates for TLS (SSL) setup using Traefik. I've followed the Traefik documentation and configured the necessary settings, but I keep getting errors.

The specific error messages I'm receiving are as follows:

```
22T15:44:37Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"api.fmdeploy.me\": unable to generate a certificate for the domains [api.fmdeploy.me]: error: one or more domains had a problem:\n[api.fmdeploy.me] acme: error: 400 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns :: no valid A records found for api.fmdeploy.me; no valid AAAA records found for api.fmdeploy.me\n" rule="Host(`api.fmdeploy.me`)" ACME CA="https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory" providerName=myresolver.acme routerName=backend@docker

time="2023-05-22T15:44:38Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"client.fmdeploy.me\": unable to generate a certificate for the domains [client.fmdeploy.me]: error: one or more domains had a problem:\n[client.fmdeploy.me] acme: error: 400 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns :: no valid A records found for client.fmdeploy.me; no valid AAAA records found for client.fmdeploy.me\n" ACME CA="https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory" routerName=frontend@docker rule="Host(`client.fmdeploy.me`)" providerName=myresolver.acme
```

I have already checked my DNS settings and ensured that the A records are correctly configured for the domains "api.fmdeploy.me" and "client.fmdeploy.me". The DNS propagation has also been given sufficient time.

Here's an overview of my setup:

- I'm using Traefik as a reverse proxy and load balancer in my Docker environment.
- I have set up the Traefik configuration to enable the ACME (Let's Encrypt) challenge for automatic TLS certificate generation.
- The issue arises specifically when Traefik attempts to generate certificates for the mentioned domains.

Additionally, to provide more context, here is the docker-compose file I'm using for my application:

```
version: "2"

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.10
    container_name: traefik
    restart: unless-stopped
    command:
      - "--log.level=ERROR"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.watch=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.tlschallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=***********@gmail.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - local-net
      - proxy

  db:
    container_name: db
    build: ./backend/docker/mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test_db
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ***********
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ***********
    volumes:
      - ./backend/docker/mysql/initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./backend/docker/mysql/conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d
      - ./backend/log/mysql:/var/log/mysql
      - persist-mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - local-net
      - proxy

  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    restart: unless-stopped
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend.rule=Host(`api.test.me`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend.service=backend"
      # The internal service port that Traefik will forward the request to it.
      - "traefik.http.services.backend.loadbalancer.server.port=36554"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app/:cached
      - ./inputfiles:/inputfiles
      - ./modelfiles:/modelfiles
      - ./outputfiles:/outputfiles
    networks:
      - local-net
      - proxy
    depends_on:
      - db
      - traefik

  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
      args:
        - URI=https://api.test.me
    restart: unless-stopped
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.rule=Host(`client.test.me`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.service=frontend"
      # The internal service port that Traefik will forward the request to it.
      - "traefik.http.services.frontend.loadbalancer.server.port=36555"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app:cached
      - ./frontend/node_modules:/app/node_modules:cached
    networks:
      - local-net
      - proxy
    depends_on:
      - db
      - backend
      - traefik

networks:
  local-net:
    driver: bridge
  proxy:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  persist-mysql:
```

I would appreciate any assistance in troubleshooting this issue. Is there anything I might be missing or any additional steps I need to take to ensure successful certificate generation?

Thank you in advance for your help!

In my setup, I attempted to use the Traefik TLS challenge to obtain ACME certificates for my domains. I configured Traefik to communicate with my DNS provider, Namecheap.com, for verification. I expected Traefik to successfully generate the certificates using the TLS challenge method.

However, despite verifying that my DNS settings and A records were correctly configured, and allowing sufficient time for DNS propagation, I encountered an error stating that no valid A or AAAA records were found for my domains during the ACME certificate generation process. This issue suggests that the Traefik TLS challenge was unable to perform the necessary DNS verification.

I would try the traefik dns challenge but namecheap.com did not provide api access, so I can't try that.

I am seeking assistance to understand any potential workarounds or alternative approaches to have https working with this setup.